# Possibilities of using abstract factories with StructureMap

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, structuremap, abstract-factory

```
public interface IExecuter
{
    void Execute();
}

public class Executer : IExecuter
{
    readonly Data _data;
    readonly IService _service;

    public Executer(Data data, IService service)
    {
        _data = data;
        _service = service;
    }

    public void Execute()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I consume the data object with id {0}", _data.Id);
        _service.DoAnything();
    }
}

public interface IService
{
    void DoAnything();
}

public class Service : IService
{
    public void DoAnything()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I do anything else");
    }
}

public class Data
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Now I need an abstract factory to create the IExecuter, because I need to pass a run-time value into the constructor.

Possibility #1 - **use a static abstract factory**:

```
public class FormularWindow
{
    public static Func<Data, IExecuter> CreateExecuter = data => {throw new NotImplementedException("");};

    public void InvokeExecuter()
    {
        var selectedData = GetSelectedData();
        var executer = CreateExecuter (selectedData);
        executer.Execute();
    }

    private static Data GetSelectedData()
    {
        return new Data { Id = 4, Description = "Test" };
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
        {
            x.For<IExecuter>().Use<Executer>();
            x.For<IService>().Use<Service>();
        });
        FormularWindow.CreateExecuter = data => ObjectFactory.With(data.GetType(), data).GetInstance<IExecuter>();

        var consumer = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<FormularWindow>();

        consumer.InvokeExecuter();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Possibility #2 - **use an abstract factory as a constructor parameter**:

```
public class FormularWindow
{
    readonly Func<Data, IExecuter> _createExecuter;

    public FormularWindow(Func<Data, IExecuter> createExecuter)
    {
        _createExecuter = createExecuter;
    }

    public void InvokeExecuter()
    {
        var selectedData = GetSelectedData();
        var executer = _createExecuter(selectedData);
        executer.Execute();
    }

    private static Data GetSelectedData()
    {
        return new Data { Id = 4, Description = "Test" };
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
        {
            x.For<IExecuter>().Use<Executer>();
            x.For<IService>().Use<Service>();
            x.For<Func<Data, IExecuter>>().Use(data => ObjectFactory.With(data.GetType(), data).GetInstance<IExecuter>());
        });


        var consumer = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<FormularWindow>();

        consumer.InvokeExecuter();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Possibility #3 - **Use a IExecuterFactory**:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
        {
            x.For<IExecuter>().Use<Executer>();
            x.For<IService>().Use<Service>();
            x.For<IExecuterFactory>().Use<ExecuterFactory>();
        });

        var consumer = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<FormularWindow>();

        consumer.InvokeExecuter();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public interface IExecuterFactory
{
    IExecuter Create(Data data);
}

public class ExecuterFactory : IExecuterFactory
{
    readonly IService _service;

    public ExecuterFactory(IService service)
    {
        _service = service;
    }

    public IExecuter Create(Data data)
    {
        return new Executer(data, _service);// ?!
    }
}


public class FormularWindow
{
    readonly IExecuterFactory _executerFactory;


    public FormularWindow(IExecuterFactory executerFactory)
    {
        _executerFactory = executerFactory;
    }

    public void InvokeExecuter()
    {
        var selectedData = GetSelectedData();
        var executer = _executerFactory.Create(selectedData);
        executer.Execute();
    }

    private static Data GetSelectedData()
    {
        return new Data { Id = 4, Description = "Test" };
    }
}
```

With possibility #3 I do not know how to implement it as you can see. I could again use `Func` in the constructor of the `ExecuterFactory`, but that would be a kind of strange, because I use an **abstract factory** inside an **abstract factory**.

There would be also a #4 possibility to inject the container, but that would be not a good idea, because of introducing a **service locator**.

I ask myself if there is a way of using **abstract factories** without `Func<>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't call that an [Abstract Factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern), it looks like the functional equivalent of what some call a Simple Factory.

I suggest you to have a look at Mark Seemann's [post about abstract factories](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/03/15/ImplementingAnAbstractFactory.aspx), he explains several options in a simple manner.

Practically, you could call your container in `ExecuterFactory` to solve your dependencies in case it resides in the same project as your composition root or instantiate them yourself `new`ing them in your manually coded factory. I prefer the manual approach, because I like the idea of keeping the usage of the container at a minimum.

Comment: I edited my question. A simple factory would ony allow to create a concrete implementation. An abstract factory return type is an abstracion in form of an interface or abstract class. This is the case in my example.

Comment: @Rookian Sorry I didn't want to start a discussion about Abstract Factory / Simple Factory definitions in this place, since it is not the point. Nonetheless, it seems you got what I was talking about and you edited your answer :) Does it suit your needs?

Comment: I am not sure if it is a good idea to newing up the Executer.

Comment: @Rookian well, you have to instantiate it somehow at run-time, I see nothing really wrong in instantiating something manually in a factory, it's its role as a pattern after all. What don't you like about it?